# WPF - Radio button control template binding "IsChecked" not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate, ischecked

I have a control template like below, and I want to get `IsChecked` property when user selects a radio button.

But when user select radio button "A" it's `IsChecked` property still show false. Why?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioBtnTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
   <Grid>
     <StackPanel Margin="5">
         <RadioButton Name="tempbtn" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="18.667" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" GroupName="{TemplateBinding GroupName}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and I use this template:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="CG" x:Name="_rdoBtnA" Content="A" Template="{DynamicResource RadioBtnTemplate}" IsChecked="True"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="CG" x:Name="_rdoBtnB" Content="B" Template="{DynamicResource RadioBtnTemplate}" />
<RadioButton GroupName="CG" x:Name="_rdoBtnC" Content="C" Template="{DynamicResource RadioBtnTemplate}" />
```

Comment: A RadioButton in the Template of a RadioButton? Doesn't make sense to me. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, I just wanna let every radio button look like the same style, does that have any other good design?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we take your example as is then you have two problems which cause the problems you are seeing.

**Issue 1:**
Firstly your design has created **six** not **three** `<RadioButton>` controls.  The three in the `<StackPanel>` and then three that are created as part of the control template.  All **six** radio buttons are now linked as part of the `GroupName="CG"` group.

As you know because they all belong to the same `CG` group only one of the six radio buttons can have the `IsChecked` property set to `True`.  The three named controls `_rdoBtnA`, `_rdoBtnB` and `_rdoBtnC` are not even visible on the screen so they can never be set to `True` (and in the case of `_rdoBtnA` is promptly set to `False` from the `XAML` declared `True` the moment the template control is bound).

To resolve this situation, remove the `GroupName="{TemplateBinding GroupName}"` from the control template definition leaving only the three top level radio buttons in the group.

**Issue 2:**  This is the issue I thought was the root of your problem to begin with.  `IsChecked={TemplateBinding IsChecked}` is only `OneWay` binding and will not update the other way.  To make the binding `TwoWay` you need to use the long-hand version of the binding definition, `IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"`

The control template now becomes this by making those two changes.

```c#
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioBtnTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <RadioButton Name="tempbtn" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="18.667" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Oh! Really thanks for your helping and let me clear my concept of binding!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use it this way:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonAsSwatchTemplate">    
            <Border x:Name="SwatchBorder" BorderThickness="1">
                <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Property=Background}" Width="15" Height="15" />
            </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="SwatchBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton Template="{StaticResource ButtonAsSwatchTemplate}"
        GroupName="CropGuidesColourRadioButtonGroup"
        IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" Margin="2" Background="Red" />
    <RadioButton Template="{StaticResource ButtonAsSwatchTemplate}"
        GroupName="CropGuidesColourRadioButtonGroup" 
        IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" Margin="2" Background="Black" />
</StackPanel>
```

taken from [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770075/templatebinding-from-a-style-datatrigger-in-controltemplate)